# Can I search for parent nodes from deep child nodes using Views?

Tags: views, nodes

I've a complicated hierarchy of nodes.
Node A contains(by node reference) multiple B nodes, each B contains multiple C nodes and so on.

Using Views will it be possible to reach C from A or vice versa given even higher depth level?

I think this is independent of D6/D7 views but I'm on D6.

There will be thousands of such nodes. Each top level A is an organization and there are a 1000 of them now. Information about each employee or department will be held in File(aka file cabinet) which again is a node).

I want to give users facility to search information from one end to another.

Update: The parent to child relationship is one to many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bunch of options.  I am using noderelationships and thinking of pairing it with reverse_node_reference.

I'd look into these modules.

D6: http://drupal.org/project/noderelationships

D6: http://drupal.org/project/reverse_node_reference (See http://drupal.org/node/798786 for some good insight)

D6, D7: http://drupal.org/project/cnr

D6: http://drupal.org/project/nodereferrer

D6: http://drupal.org/project/backreference

D6: http://drupal.org/project/partners

D7: http://drupal.org/project/references

Comment: Which one do you recommend and why?

Comment: reverse_node_reference is the one I am pursuing because of what is said in this comment, http://drupal.org/node/798786#comment-2966208

Comment: I've parent-child one to many relationship and just now realized both side node reference will not be possible with these modules that is from parent to child and vice versa since parent will then need to have unlimited node reference to children

Comment: With these modules when given C you should be able to find A.  And Given A you should be able to see all B -> C combinations.   Having those two cases in a single View is probably not possible with these modules.

Comment: Given A's information how to show information of D in Views? When the relationship(1 to many) A->B->C->D

Comment: You'd most likely have multiple D nodes.  You'd have to set up a View "Relationship" for each step using the node reference fields.  Meaning you'd need a View "Relationship" for A->B, then one from B->C, and then one for C->D.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do it with the [Corresponding Node References](http://drupal.org/project/cnr) module. Otherwise you can't do reverse references at all. You'll use relationships, of course, to go both ways.

Comment: Thanks for this module which is really useful. But what I want to know if we can join view relationships than 2 levels. In SQL it'd be joining 3 or more tables together

Comment: Views can do relationships at more than one level.

Comment: what about 2-5 levels? Do you have an example?

Comment: I've parent-child one to many relationship and just now realized both side node reference will not be possible with these modules that is from parent to child and vice versa since parent will then need to have unlimited node reference to children